# Using Table values on Matrix to generate sum

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have this distance table

[image]

and I have the premieter distance for triangle to calculate the path

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I m trying to use the premiter betwen triangles to calculate the path using the tables

For example the first path from the second table 1 -> 5 -> 9 -> 1 path 
we look at the table and we find the edges 1->5 distance i s670.7 and 5->9 is  and so on and sum the values to generate a new table.

This is what I came up with but its not working can any one assist

```
Do[H[i, j]] = Sum[Distancem[[ddp[i, j]], [ddp[i, j]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
```

then plot the results of the triangles

The final distance table would be some thing like

[image]

Comment: This question makes no sense.  What triangle(s)?  What path(s)?

Comment: Would help greatly if had distances and triangle data as selectable text instead of images

Comment: What does "perimeter between triangles..." even mean?  What does "calculate the minimum distance between we first..." even mean?

Comment: alright the distance matrix L= [ 50 50 ; 10 100; 15 20; 45 350; 720 80 ;890 105;125 650 ; 190 780; 25 920 ;55 100; 700 150; 500 500]  after I construm the distance array Distancem = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];   then run the loopDo[Distancem[[i, j]] = 
     Sqrt[(L[[i, 1]] - L[[j, 1]])^2 + (L[[i, 2]] - L[[j, 2]])^2], {i, 
     1, n}, {j, 1, n}] Distancem // MatrixForm;    construct then on table form N[Distancem, 4] // TableForm you will have to past the command on mathematica to understand what I m talking aboiut

Comment: David if you have three  states  and each state  has three cities that a sales man is travelling between  provided he  only  cross one city at each state  example state one has city 1 ,2,3  state 2 city 4,5,6     the sales man should take 1 -> 4 -> 8 then back to 1 formign atriangle

Comment: How can I use the 1 5 9 1  as elements for  a different matrix for example  I have the distance 12x12  i want to use D(1,5) + D(5,9)+D(9,1)

Comment: I did add it @Manuel--Moe--G

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't provided copy-able data, I'll just make some up. Here is a 5 by 5 version of the distance matrix and a length-3 version of the index list ddp:

```
d = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {5, 5}];
dist = d + Transpose[d] - 2 DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[d]];
ddp = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 1}}
dist // MatrixForm

{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 1}}
```

[image]

Now to calculate the distances "around the triangles":

```
dall = Table[dist[[ddp[[i, 1]], ddp[[i, 2]]]] + 
             dist[[ddp[[i, 2]], ddp[[i, 3]]]] + 
             dist[[ddp[[i, 3]], ddp[[i, 1]]]], {i, Length[ddp]}]

{323.004, 317.76, 279.409}
```

and your desired output form is:

```
Thread@{ddp, dall}

{{{1, 2, 3}, 473.769}, {{3, 4, 1}, 349.453}, {{2, 5, 1}, 283.595}}
```

Comment: Place your information in the question and make it possible to copy/paste it into Matheamtica. As it is, your L matrix comes out as 50*50*50... instead of 50,50,50...

Comment: Hello Bill I found the answer 
Table[N[Distancem[[i, j]] + Distancem[[j, k]] + Distancem[[k, i]], 
  5], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 5, 8}, {k, 9, 12}]